# Tomcat 9 - location in Linux Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat

I am trying to deploy my Java Web Application on the apache tomcat server. I want to deploy it manually without using `eclipse`.

It already took a lot of time to install `tomcat apache 9` in Linux. Found a lot of resources but many of them had the `404` error or a wrong link to download the package.

I also checked google to find any relevant article for the folder location of `apache tomcat 9`. But was not able to figure it out.

can anyone tell me the location of apache tomcat 9 so that I can deploy my web application, specifically in `ubuntu 18.04 & apache tomcat 9`

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT: I figured out the problem was I was changing the default directory.. One of the [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/install-tomcat-9-ubuntu-1804) creates the directory with a different name, which was creating the problem to find the tomcat. Apologies & thanks for responding

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: This link worked out 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/install-tomcat-9-ubuntu-1804

Comment: Yeah, I was about to send you that link and trying to figure out how you got 404s given that's the second result searching for "tomcat 9 ubuntu"

Comment: There are couple of em there... I feel whenever i use wget it shows 404. Not totally sure about it

Answer (score 3):

The webapps are located in /var/lib/tomcat9

You can run the following command.

```
$ tree  /var/lib/tomcat9 -L 2
/var/lib/tomcat9
├── common
│   └── classes
├── conf -> /etc/tomcat9
├── logs -> ../../log/tomcat9
├── server
│   └── classes
├── shared
│   └── classes
├── webapps
│   └── ROOT
└── work -> ../../cache/tomcat9
```

Comment: I tried finding tomcat in /var/lib/tomcat9. But was not able to. even the command didn't worked show "command not found & could not open file" errors.

Comment: @abhigyannayak `tree` is not installed by default on some systems. You can use `ls -R` to recursively list a directory's content.